# Scala parallelization method

Tags: scala

Having a look at the forall method implementation, how could this method be parallel?

```
  def forall(p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
    var result = true
    breakable {
      for (x <- this)
        if (!p(x)) { result = false; break }
    }
    result
  }
```

As I understand for better parallelization, avoid using var's and prefer val's. How is this now supposed to work if I use forall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at a non-parallel version of `forall`.

A parallel version looks like this (provided by a parallel collection, in this case  [ParIterableLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike)):

```
def forall(pred: T => Boolean): Boolean = {
  tasksupport.executeAndWaitResult
    (new Forall(pred, splitter assign new DefaultSignalling with VolatileAbort))
}
```

To get a parallel collection, insert a `.par`, for example:

```
List.range(1, 10).par.forall(n => n % 2 == 0)
```

If you use an IDE like IntelliJ, just "zoom" into that `forall`, and you'll see the code above. Otherwise here is the source of [ParIterableLike](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/parallel/ParIterableLike.scala#L525) (thanks @Kigyo for sharing the URL).

Comment: Where did you get this from? Can you post the path to the API?

Comment: It's here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/parallel/ParIterableLike.scala#L525 `ParIterableLike` also defines several other parallel methods

Comment: Just "zoom" in, otherwise look for ParIterableLike.scala

Comment: @Kigyou Thanks for your comment - I have added it to the answer.